# Inserting in MySQL Table

Tags: mysql, c, database, network-programming

I am trying to insert data into mysql table through mysql C client, through the step written below.

The **command** is of the Form : (A variable string generated at run time)

```
INSERT INTO department values('Statistics','Taylor',395051.74)
```

which is correct for MySQL.

```
if (mysql_query(con, command))
{

printf("Done\n");
}
printf("\n%s\n",command);
```

But my database shows no change. No rows get inserted, is there any way the above steps could not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that mysql_query returns a zero if it is successful, and an error code if it's unsucessful [MySQL Docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-query.html). I think you might be treating it backward. So I think it's issuing an error you're not catching.

As a guess of what might be wrong, try telling it what columns you're inserting into:

```
INSERT INTO department (`column1`,`column2`,`column3`) 
values ('Statistics','Taylor',395051.74)
```